# Amplifier Output Clipping

Tags: amplifier

When an amplifier output clips at a certain voltage, does that mean the maximum voltage that its output can provide is the voltage value where the clipping occurs?

Comment: It may also mean that the input signal is clipping. Just keep that in mind. Different stages in the signal chain may clip at different points for different reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an amplifier output clips at a certain voltage, does that mean
>   the maximum voltage that its output can provide is the voltage value
>   where the clipping occurs?

It's load dependent. The no-load clipping point is usually the maximum voltage swing but, if you place a several mA load on the output, it will clip at a lower voltage level. Be also aware that feedback resistors form a small output load and, values that "low" means clipping occurs at a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

I would say that the voltage you see when clipping occurs is the maximum voltage that the amplifier can provide temporarily. Depending on how it is designed, it is possible that it is not sized to provide a steady DC voltage so high (or low), while also providing some current.

It is pretty safe to assume that you will never see anything above (or below) clipping, unless something bad happens to the amp i.e. it breaks down.